# Turn off Location Services from my Android App

Tags: java, android, location-services

Salaam my friends,

Is there any specific code that I can use to turn off the location services in my phone from my app?

Regards,
Tareq Al-Aqarbeh﻿

Comment: sorry mate check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481653/how-to-disable-location-service-programmatically

Comment: The answer is here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546214/android-once-click-off-on-location-services

Comment: Thank you Samara and Ronner. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot actually mess directly with the device settings.
All you can do is start the location settings intent through your app so the user can turn on/off what you need

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```